# Carrierwave - different file paths for different versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am uploading an image that I am making many versions of, and I want to be able to put each version in a different folder. For example:

```
class ItunesArtworkUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base 
  DIMENSIONS = [1024, 1024]  

  {  
      :iphone_small_29x29   => { size: [29, 29], filename: "icon-small.png" },  
      :iphone_57x57         => { size: [57, 57], filename: "icon.png" }  
  }  
  # resize

  def filename
    "iTunesArtwork.png"
  end

end
```

The original ItunesArtwork.png is being put into uploads/foo/itunes_artwork/iTunesArtwork.png. Now for each version I want them to be in their own folders underneath "foo" like this:

```
uploads/foo/itunes_artwork/iTunesArtwork.png  
uploads/foo/itunes_artwork/icon-small.png  
uploads/foo/itunes_artwork/icon.png
```

I've tried

```
:iphone_small_29x29   => { size: [29, 29], filename: "/icon-small/icon-small.png"},
```

but that gives me this as a resulting filepath:

```
uploads/foo/itunes_artwork/icon-small/icon-small.png
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!